# Objective C - How to access NSNotification inner objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnotifications

I want to access a inner object from a notification. I need to get the key AVSystemController_AudioVolumeChangeReasonNotificationParameter.

If I call [sender object] I get this output. But if I call

```
[[sender object] userInfo]
```

I only get "unrecognized selector sent to instance". Why is that?

NSLog(@"%@", [sender object]) output:

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x157a30 {name = AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification; object = AVSystemController: 0x1616c0; userInfo = {
    "AVSystemController_AudioCategoryNotificationParameter" = "Audio/Video";
    "AVSystemController_AudioVolumeChangeReasonNotificationParameter" = ExplicitVolumeChange;
    "AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter" = 1;
}}
```

If it is not possible to access userInfo, can I get the output of NSLog to do a string search?

Comment: Can you edit and post the whole "unrecognized selector" error?  The error is either not about the `[[sender object] userInfo]` invocation or the `[sender object]` is not the same as printed by the NSLog() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output from NSLog actually looks like the output of

```
NSLog(@"%@", sender);
```

Are you sure you were calling [sender object]?

object is often the Object that posted the notification. In your case most likely an object with class AVSystemController

The userinfo can be accessed with

```
[sender userInfo]
```

So please try

```
NSLog(@"%@", [sender userInfo]);
```

---

BTW: If you try to map the function of the volume-buttons to some other function (for example "Take Photo"-Action) your app won't be approved. Just in case.